# SQLite database is locked, but only for insert from PHP script run at command line

Tags: php, sqlite, command-line, locking

I have a PHP script that does the following in the order presented:

- Connect to a MySQL database
- Retrieve a single row of data
- Close the MySQL database connection
- Connect to a SQLite database on the local file system
- Insert the row of data into the SQLite database
- Close the SQLite database connection

I'm using PDO as the vehicle for both MySQL and SQLite. Here is the code for the insert:

```
$sqlite = new PDO('sqlite:activity.sqlite');
$sqlite->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$lite = <<<LITE
INSERT INTO Transactions (Date,Transactions,ActiveMembers,Amount) 
VALUES
('$day',
'$trans',
'$active',
'$amount');
LITE;

try
{
    $sqlite->exec($lite);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

*(please forgive the usage of variables in the query, rather than a proper prepared statement; I removed the bound parameters to see if that was the problem)*

Using other tools (SQLite Manager for Firefox, SQLite Database Browser for Windows), I am able to access the database and write to it.

This script is the only thing that touches this particular database. The permissions on the database file are `777`. Nothing else has it, or its containing directory, open when the script runs.

When running the script (using `php -f`), the portion that tries to insert into the SQLite database creates the journal file, takes about 10-15 seconds, and then returns the error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked`.

So my question, then, is this:

**Is there something about running a PHP script from command line that prevents interaction with a SQLite database? If so, what? If not, what could be the issue here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across the same problem. After using the **fuser** command and finding which process had created a sticky lock I knew the rogue:

```
[root]# fuser cms.db
cms.db:               4511
[root]# ps aux | grep 4511
nobody    4511  0.0  3.2  74560 25160 ?   S    Oct13   2:00 php-fpm
[root]# /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
```

**PHP-fpm** was the guilty one so restarting the service did the trick. That must have been a bug in the PHP version I was running (5.4) and may still be.

Comment: Weird. Yes, this is what did it. I was also using PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to clear your connection to SQLite, i.e. after your code, set

```
$sqlite = null;
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Adding this bit didn't solve the problem, unfortunately. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, it helps to rule that out. To answer your question: Nothing prevents PHP from interacting with a SQLite DB from the command line. Typically, issues like these are caused by user permissions and connections that remain open.

Comment: Aye, that's what I thought. The trouble is, the file permissions are wide open, and I've tried running the script as root, so that can't be the issue. Is there anything in the code I presented above that might be opening a connection prior to sending the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Code looks fine, nothing appears to be out of place. Any chance that one of the variables (`$day`, `$trans`, `$active`, `$amount'`) contain an unescaped string of some kind that breaks the SQL syntax?

Comment: No, none. I echoed out the generated query string and ran it against the database in SQLite Manager, and it inserted just fine.

Comment: My last guess would be to make 100% sure that no locks remain (try e.g. http://technosophos.com/content/sqlite-database-locked-error-and-unlocking-database), and then run the process again with the updated code which makes sure that the connection is closed. Good luck!

Comment: I did not. I ended up giving up and creating a full MySQL database to handle the work. I appreciate you checking up, though.